# Tensorflow on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi2, tensorflow

I'm trying to install `Tensorflow` on `Raspberry Pi`. The OS is `Ubuntu Mate`, `python2.7` and `PIP` version is `7.1.2`

When I run this

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

it tells that

> "tensorflow-0.5.0... is not a supported wheel on this platform."

Is it possible to install `Tensorflow` on `Raspberry`?
And someone knows what I'm missing?

Comment: Compiling tensorflow from source might work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Raspberry Pi is a 32-bit architecture, and the TensorFlow program was made for a 64-bit. 
I am not sure how well A Raspberry Pi can handle it, but you could install a virtual machine and run the TensorFlow inside there.

Maybe the newer generations of the Rasberry Pi could handle this a bit better, but the original ones, will probably struggle to run this setup.

You could do the training on a more powerful machine and just run the learned machine on the Rasberry Pi, that might be feasible in terms of computing power.

Comment: may be the OP wants to create a Raspberry Pi cluster. The Idea crossed my mind too, and would be fascinating to see.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to build a GPU cluster? I mean regarding cost. A decent GPU is around 350€. You'd get 10 Raspis for that. And still the single GPU highly outnumbers the 10 Raspis wrt the amount of learning processes that can be run in parallel.

Answer (score 8):

It is now possible to install Tensorflow on Raspberry Pi. There are detailed build instructions at https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi as well as an unofficial downloadable build.

Answer (score 1):

x86 is for intel-like cpu and 64 is for 64 bits that's not Raspberry pi's hardware...

Comment: Raspberry Pi is an ARM processor not and Intel processor. Of note for this answer.

Comment: It might be possible to compile it for the ARM architecture since the project is open source...